# PCF with git and vault: Vault port must be defined in 'vault.port', not using : syntax

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

in my cloud config PCF Service.
Git part is fine, Vault is causing issue:-
{
    "composite": [{"git": {
        "password": "****",
        "label": "develop",
        "uri": "https://*****/config-server-files",
        "username": "*****"
    },
    "vault":{
        "port":"8200",
 "scheme": "https",
 "host": ":*****"
    }}]
}

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the command you're running? What is the exact error message? What version of SCS are you using? What version is your Config Server instance?

Comment: Thanks for the cpmment Daniel . I was trying to configure it on the Cloud foundry using web app for PCF. I went thru the spring socumentation and able to find a solution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
The correct config for using multiple backends(Git + Vault) on config server is
**
**

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "composite": [
        {
            "vault": {
                "host": "***",
                "port": 8200,
                "scheme": "https",
                "backend": "cf/***/secret",
                "defaultKey": "****",
                "profileSeparator": ",",
                "skipSslValidation": true
            }
        },
        {
            "git": {
                "password": "****",
                "uri": "****/config-server-files",
                "username": "****",
                "basedir": "/home/vcap/app/config-repo/composite-1-default",
                "ignoreLocalSshSettings": true,
                "label": "develop"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**
**